# Which SQL is costlier and why?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

```
Select DISTINCT Dept,SUM(Salary) OVER (PARTITION BY Dept) from Table

Select Dept, SUM(Salary) FROM Table GROUP BY Dept
```

Both the above queries produce same result.
In my opinion second query is costlier as it is using GROUP BY function which is costlier.
Is it the correct explanation if ans is correct or is it something else?

Comment: @GordonLinoff You are right.

Comment: You could run them both and look at the plans :)

Answer (score 2):

As with any question regarding performance, it is best to test the queries on your data on your system.  Factors such as indexes and table size can determine which is faster.  If you are interested in questions like this, you need to [learn about execution plans](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/performance/display-an-actual-execution-plan?view=sql-server-ver15) and how to read them.

That said, I would expect the first one to be more expensive, because the aggregated salary is probably first calculated and then aligned with every row.  Then the duplicates are removed.

But the optimizer is free to do what it wants, including producing exactly the same execution plan for the two queries.

Answer (score 0):

How did you conclude that the `group by` function is costlier?

If you are using Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio, then you can let the application tell you which version is more expensive. See guidelines in the screenshot below.

My initial findings (without any data) show that the `group by` version is less intense for the SQL engine.

[image: SSMS guidelines]

Answer (score 0):

Examine the plans and measure the CPU and Logical IO cost of both queries.  EG

```
use AdventureWorks2017
go
set statistics time on 
set statistics IO on 
go

select JobTitle, sum(SickLeaveHours) SickLeaveHours
from HumanResources.Employee 
group by JobTitle


select distinct JobTitle, sum(SickLeaveHours) over (partition by JobTitle) SickLeaveHours
from HumanResources.Employee

go
set statistics time off
set statistics IO off
```

The second query has a more complicated plan and a higher cost:

GROUP BY query

```
Table 'Worktable'. Scan count 0, logical reads 0, physical reads 0, page server reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, page server read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob page server reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0, lob page server read-ahead reads 0.
Table 'Employee'. Scan count 1, logical reads 9, physical reads 0, page server reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, page server read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob page server reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0, lob page server read-ahead reads 0.
```

DISTINCT query

```
 Table 'Worktable'. Scan count 3, logical reads 849, physical reads 0, page server reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, page server read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob page server reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0, lob page server read-ahead reads 0.
 Table 'Employee'. Scan count 1, logical reads 9, physical reads 0, page server reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, page server read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob page server reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0, lob page server read-ahead reads 0.
```